# Win10: How to add microphone option into Windows Mobility Center

Tags: windows

Good day!

Is there a way to arrange the tiles in Windows Mobility Center? By adding the "Microphone", I wish to mute/unmute microphone from Windows Mobility Center.

Thank you.

My current Windows Mobility Center looks like:

[image]